# What voice compression algorithm to use?

Tags: vb.net

which algorithm used for voice compression mailing and decompression

Comment: What medium are you going to transfer the data over? The available bandwith influences the choice of the codec very much.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best voice codecs out there is G.729, which is currently owned and licensed by Digium (http://www.digium.com), makers of Asterisk. It is an extremely effective low-loss audio codec intended for vocal wavelengths (hence why it's used for VoIP telephony). It also handles jitter very well (the change in height of latency over time), and uses only 8kb/s.

Answer (score 0):

These days everybody from Skype to Google to phone companies do it with mp3. The minimum bitrate is a bit high but you get excellent audio for that bitrate. And the tech is proven and solid.

But apart from mp3 there are other, typically old-school, low bandwidth codecs which have been used to encode the human voice. The standard in telephony used to be u-law (that's mu-law) and A-law. A fairy recent speech specific codec that looks interesting is [Speex](http://www.speex.org/)